# Compiling Error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost

Tags: linux

Im trying to compile something in Ubuntu 14.04 and get this error message while libboost package is already installed.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I hope somebody can help me fast to resolve this error.

Many thanks!

Comment: might fixed it. 
will update

Comment: Fixed it but now I am getting this error:

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: err

Comment: Call `make` as `LIBS=-ldl make`

Comment: thanks but its still not working when calling with LIBS=ldl

Comment: You now say "LIBS=ldl". Have you forgotten the hyphen sign betwen `=` and `ldl`? You need to call make as `LIBS=-ldl make`.

Comment: Yes I've used LIBS=-ldl make but I still have the same error which I have posted before. Thanks for your taking your time.

Comment: Do you have `libc6-dev` package installed?

Comment: Yes libc6-dev is already installed.

Comment: What happens if you do `LDLIBS=-ldl make` instead?

Comment: Just tried it and its still the same. I also can't find something working on here.

Comment: Could you please expand on what you are trying to compile? I.e. how does the Makefile look?

Comment: Im trying to compile Litecoin 0.8.7.4 with gitian-builder. I hope what I did is right because I'm new to linux but I am already familiar.
https://pastebin.com/3tWhsRP5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `libboost-all-dev` package.

Comment: thanks I just managed to fixed this.

Now I have this problem:

Comment: Hello, the output is the following:


/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

I hope somebody knows how to fix this.
libssl-dev is installed but libel.so.2 is missing. libc6 is not adding it.

Thanks for answering!